# I'm getting an error in my nodejs project when including Datatables

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, datatables, handlebars.js

I'm stuck in a problem where I cannot get datatables to work with my node.js project. When I try to initalise the table i get an error saying,

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

I have tried diffent ways to mitigate this issue but I'm not getting anywhere.

I'm using handlebars as my templating engine. And using a Bootstrap 4 Admin Template.

This is the code I'm using,

**This is my table.hbs**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app-assets/vendors/css/tables/datatable/datatables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app-assets/vendors/css/tables/extensions/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app-assets/vendors/css/tables/datatable/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">

  <!-- BEGIN: Content-->
    <div class="app-content content">
        <div class="content-header row">
        </div>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="content-body">
                <!-- Active Orders -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Active Order</h4>
                                <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="la la-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>
                                <div class="heading-elements">
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm round btn-primary btn-glow"><i class="la la-plus font-medium-1"></i>
                                        Add User</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="userTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Extension</th>
                                                    <th>Username</th>
                                                    <th>Department</th>
                                                    <th>Allowed Credits</th>
                                                    <th>Balance Credits</th>
                                                    <th>Renewal Mode</th>
                                                    <th>Billing Mode</th>
                                                    <th>Rate</th>
                                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                {{#each rows}}
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>{{this.TXT_STATION_NO}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{this.TXT_USERNAME}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{this.TXT_DEPARTMENT}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{this.TOTAL_CREDITS}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{this.BALANCE_CREDITS}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{this.CREDIT_RENEWAL_MODE}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{this.CDR_BILLING_MODE}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{this.TXT_RATE}}</td>
                                                    <td><span class="badge badge-info">Edit</span> <span class="badge badge-danger">Delete</span></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                {{/each}}
                                            </tbody>
                                            <tfoot>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Extension</th>
                                                    <th>Username</th>
                                                    <th>Department</th>
                                                    <th>Allowed Credits</th>
                                                    <th>Balance Credits</th>
                                                    <th>Renewal Mode</th>
                                                    <th>Billing Mode</th>
                                                    <th>Rate</th>
                                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tfoot>
                                        </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Active Orders -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END: Content-->
    <!-- BEGIN: Page Vendor JS-->
    <script src="app-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app-assets/vendors/js/tables/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app-assets/vendors/js/tables/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app-assets/vendors/js/tables/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="app-assets/vendors/js/tables/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app-assets/vendors/js/tables/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app-assets/vendors/js/tables/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
    <!-- END: Page Vendor JS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Page JS-->
    <script src="app-assets/js/scripts/tables/datatables-extensions/datatable-button/datatable-html5.js"></script>
    <!-- END: Page JS-->
```

This is just the body, the begining and the end of the html is in my Layouts. I have tried having the scripts and the css related to the datatables in that as well but still did not work.

If you need anything else please let be know I'll share it ASAP.

Always appriciate your help guys.

Comment: Are you including jQuery too in your project?DataTables depends on jQuery.

Comment: @cheesyMan I tried including it but still did not work

Comment: Where’s the configuration code for the table__ like the script